# Is it NOT possible to have links to pages out of the root directory using the bootstrap dropdown nav?

Tags: drop-down-menu, navbar

Ok So almost everything works fine for me. When I try to use this as a template in Dreamweaver and create web pages, the links work and the drop down menu works too. But the drop down only works if the pages I've created are in the same root directory. If I create other folders and save web pages in there, I can get to those pages from the drop down, but once I'm at the page that's inside of another folder and try to use the drop down to navigate from there, I can't. It won't drop down again. I have to click on another link that isn't inside of the folder, like the home link for example. I thought maybe it was a path issue but I've also tried to make the paths absolute instead of relative but that hasn't worked either. I have been Googling for days to see if anyone else has had this same issue come up for them but haven't had any luck.

I have a feeling it's going to be something so easy and simple that I'm not thinking of or overlooking but I'm just not having any luck.

Below is the code that I've been using as an example from the download. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be so wonderful!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">

    <script src="../js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  
    });  
</script>


      <!-- This code is taken from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html -->

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="../test2.html">In the Root</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../resources/test1.html">In Subfolder</a></li>
                                <li><a href="file:///Users/ugb484/Desktop/initializr/resources/test3.html">Absolute</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">     <\/script>')</script>

    <script src="../js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/main.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  
    });  
</script>


    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
```